# Sort tags in a headline

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

When we add tags to a headline, they just get appended. For instance,

```
* Head 1 :A:C:B:
* Head 2 :B:A:C:
```

Is there a way I can sort these tags so we get:

```
* Head 1 :A:B:C:
* Head 2 :A:B:C:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort tags alphabetically using:

```
(setq org-tags-sort-function 'org-string-collate-lessp)
```

> Documentation: When set, tags are sorted using this function as a
>   comparator.

Comment: Thanks. But how is it supposed to work? I added that line to ~/.doom.d/config.el (I use Doom Emacs). But nothing happens. Tags get added just as usual --- unsorted, in the order in which they are added

Comment: The sort applies when you set the tags using the org-set-tags-command (C-c C-q).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's already in Org.

What about

```
(defun my-org-sort-tags ()
  "On a heading sort the tags."
  (interactive)
  (when (org-at-heading-p)
    (org-set-tags (sort (org-get-tags) #'string<))))
```

for a start?

Activate with

```
M-x my-org-sort-tags
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But is there a way to make it work automatically? So, the tags are sorted as they are added.

Comment: Okay, it is already in Org see the other answer from [user:jagrg].